# Problemas con sessiones al momento de subirlo a un hosting

Tags: php, mysql, session

Desarrolle un proyecto y al momento de ejecutarlo en mi servidor local no tengo ningún problema, pero luego al momento de subirlo a un hosting no me deja iniciar session.
Revise la conexión, la ruta de la session.save_path y todo esta bien, pero me aparece este error en el archivo error:

```
[15-May-2021 22:58:24 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/truxcode/public_html/models/conexion.php:1) in /home/truxcode/public_html/view/main.php on line 1
```

Y mi archivo main esta así

```
<?php session_start();
require 'config/config.php';
date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>MESA DE PARTES</title>

    <script src="view/public/plugins/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    <script src="view/public/plugins/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.css"></script>
    <link href="view/public/assets/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <!-- <link href="view/public/assets/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet"> -->

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="view/public/assets/css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

alguna ayuda por favor

Comment: Que tiene tu archivo `config.php`?

Comment: <?php
const SERVERURL = "https://www.truxcode.com/";

Comment: Hay un mensaje de error/warning o print en conexion.php o main.php, puedes ir haciendo debug buscando puntos de parada donde asignas valor a tus variables

Comment: qué contiene `conexion.php` ? Y desde donde se está requiriendo?

Comment: Bueno, ya me salió, puse session_start() en mi index que estaba al inicio de mi proyecto y se logro